# como puedo almacenar cadenas de caracteres en un arreglo tridimensional entero en c

Tags: array, c

tengo un ejercicio donde tengo que utilizar un lote de prueba que contiene numeros y meses, lo que no puedo lograr es almacenarlos en el mismo arreglo tridimensional

```
void carga(int array[m][n][l])
{
    int hot, nac, tur;
    char mes[10];
    printf ("Ingrese un hotel (1-3, 0 para terminar): ");
    scanf ("%d", &hot);
    while (hot>3)
    {
        printf ("Numero de hotel incorrecto, por favor intente nuevamnete");
        printf ("Ingrese un hotel (1-3): ");
        scanf ("%d", &hot);
    }
    while (hot!=0)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf ("Ingrese el mes (6-8): ");
        scanf ("%s", &mes);
        printf ("Ingrese la nacionalidad (1: Argentina, 2: Brasil, 3: Otra): ");
        scanf ("%d", &nac);
        printf ("Ingrese la cantidad de turistas: ");
        scanf ("%d", &tur);
        array[hot][mes][nac]=tur;
        printf ("Numero de hotel incorrecto, por favor intente nuevamnete");
        printf ("Ingrese un hotel (1-3): ");
        scanf ("%d", &hot);
    }
    if (hot==0)
    {
        puts("La carga de datos a finalizado");
    }
}
```

el problema es que no puedo almacenarlo en el arreglo porque esta declarado como entero

Answer (score 0):

> el problema es que no puedo almacenarlo en el arreglo porque esta declarado como entero

Nadie en su sano juicio te va a pedir que almacenes caracteres en un entero, sería como pedirte guardar un zapato en la nevera.

Lo que tienes que hacer es leer el número del mes (como entero) y asunto seleccionado:

```
int mes;
scanf ("%d", &mes);
```